# Configuring Spring bean if not @Profiles active

Tags: java, spring, configuration

The documentation for the [@Profile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation is not very clear on whether multiple active profile names are AND'd or OR'd together.

I would like a bean to be configured if neither "test" nor "integration-test" profiles are active. I have tried the following but it does not work (appear to OR the conditions).

```
@Bean
@Profile({"!test", "!integration-test"})
SomeLogicNotForTests someLogicNotForTests() {
  return new SomeLogicNotForTests();
}
```

The only work around I can think of is to remove this annotation and instead `@Autowired` and Environment into the bean itself and test the `environment.getActiveProfiles()`

Is there any way to make it AND the conditions? If not could the annotation be extended to do that?

Comment: Depends on which Spring version you are using.

Comment: Spring 4.0.8-RELEASE

Comment: Spring 4+ has conditional beans (the `@Profile` is one of those conditions). You can implement your own rules for whatever you want. But wouldn't it be easier to just only include this configuration for your tests instead of always ...

Comment: Thanks. I can create my own condition by implementing `org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition` and use that to check the active profiles in the environment so that a bean is not configured during tests. I had hoped there might be an easier way using @Profile directly